# asp.net - Setting the default value for a dropdown list based on the value of another dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a little new to ASP.NET C# so I need some assistance.

I have a website with two dropdown lists: gender and selective service.

Both lists are populated with data from a database. The selective service field has 3 options: Y, N and N/A.

Is it possible to have the page automatically set the selective service default value to N/A when Female is selected and to set the default to N when Male is selected?

If you need any more details, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: possible. question: from database, how are you getting fields for gender? 'M', 'F' or "Male", "Female"?

Comment: Yes, can you post what you have tried so that we know what you have named your drop-downs. Basically you use the onChange event for the first dropdown in which you use an if statement to see which one was selected, then change the second Dropdown selecteditem (by index or text)

Comment: also, how are you binding data? You can do it OnDataBinding event for selectservice dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `OnSelectedIndexChanged` to your gender dropdown and for a start you will also set the `AutoPostBack` property to true, like so:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlGender" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlGender_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
```

Then on `ddlGender_OnSelectedIndexChanged` you check the selected value and set the desired value to the selected service dropdown, like so:

```
void ddlGender_OnSelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlGender.SelectedValue == "F")
    {
        ddlSelective.SelectedValue = "N/A"
    }
    // more code here
}
```

AutoPostBack property set to true will cause immediate full page postback after selection. When you have this working, you can do that with using `UpdatePanel`, to do your dropdowns update through AJAX. But that's already another story that you can google out.

Comment: Thanks for your input, this seems to work well. Just out of curiosity, can this be done in any way so that it changes dynamically instead of using the post back?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with AJAX. The common way of doing it with ASP.NET is using UpdatePanel panel control as I have pointed out. This will not fore full post back. Google it out and check some video.